# JAXB: Global XmlAccessType setting?

Tags: jaxb

I want to explicitly map fields in my classes to XML, so I'm using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` at the package level via `package-info.java`. However, since I have multiple distinct packages, I'm wondering: is there a way to set `XmlAccessType.NONE` globally? I couldn't find anything in the unofficial guide (http://jaxb.java.net/guide/), but I certainly could have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a global setting.  Configuring this at the package level is the broadest scope available with [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).

For More Information on `@XmlAccessorType`

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thanks, Blaise...that's what I suspected...just wanted to confirm.